# On-demand library download/install for rare features at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

Let's say that my application's size is 5MB, and it has a feature only a few users would need. The feature requires an external Nuget library, but the library's size is 50MB. In this case, including the library to my application seems like a big overhead.

I think my app would not crash if I don't try to use the library at runtime, even if the library does not exist on the system. But how to download and install the library before using it? Is that practical? I mean, if it is very difficult, then just including the library would be an option.

Comment: It's possible to download a library on demand and load it runtime, but it's kinda iffy. What about the option to choose between two installs?

Comment: Install a NuGet package at runtime? NuGet is for build-time dependencies. Perhaps what you mean is not to include the DLL with the app? You'd need an endpoint to download the DLL from though

Comment: A nuget is nothing more than an automated download of libraries / version control. You can also reference the library without using nuget. So the source doesn't have to be nuget to download it